# How to get Scilab 6.0.1 working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, java, openjdk, scilab

I have installed clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and installed Scilab from repository here with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

After installation I tried to launch it from GUI (*Applications → Other → Scilab*) - it does not start.
Then I tried to launch it from terminal with `scilab` command. Terminal output is as follows:

```
$ scilab
/usr/bin/scilab-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so it can't find Java. I reported [bug 1762999](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1762999) about this problem.

I checked existence of `libjava.so`:

```
$ dpkg -S libjava.so  
openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjava.so
```

so it is in place.

What should I do to get Scilab 6.0.1 working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## * Repository-based method (Scilab works, ATOMS does not work)

**Update 2021-09-30**.
Nowadays Scilab is working again, installable by `sudo apt-get install scilab`. ATOMS still does not work because of [bug 1765503](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scilab/+bug/1765503).

---

## * Binary download method (fully-functional, seems to be really recommended)

So if you need fully-functional Scilab you should remove deb-packaged version with

```
sudo apt-get purge scilab scilab scilab-cli scilab-data scilab-doc scilab-full-bin scilab-include scilab-minimal-bin scilab-sivp scilab-test
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and use latest binary archive 6.1.1 from official site and run the commands below (download, extract, add to PATH, set shortcuts and MIME-association):

```
mkdir ~/Software
cd  ~/Software
wget https://www.scilab.org/download/6.1.1/scilab-6.1.1.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xzf scilab-6.1.1.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd scilab-6.1.1
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/Software/scilab-6.1.1/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/Software/scilab-6.1.1/bin" >> ~/.profile
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp -a ~/Software/scilab-6.1.1/share/{icons,applications,mime} ~/.local/share/
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/
update-menus
```

The ATOMS and other components will work as expected. Do not forget to install `build-essential` package to run Xcos Modelica simulations.

## * Flatpak method

Currently Scilab 6.1.1 is available from [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.scilab.Scilab).

To install use command below:

```
flatpak install flathub org.scilab.Scilab
```

To run use its shortcuts or command below:

```
flatpak run org.scilab.Scilab
```

## * AppImage download method (fully-functional)

We need to download the latest release from [corresponding page](https://appimage.github.io/Scilab/) or manually:

```
mkdir ~/Software
cd ~/Software
wget https://github.com/davidcl/Scilab.AppDir/releases/download/6.1.0-1/Scilab-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x Scilab-x86_64.AppImage
ln -s Scilab-x86_64.AppImage scilab
```

and then add it to PATH with

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/Software/" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/Software/" >> ~/.profile
```

As the result you will get Scilab working. But there is no MIME associations (yet).

---

If you want to get Scilab 5.5.2 working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS see [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1053015/66509). But be careful with `libcurl4` removal!

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps to run scilab on (x)ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver):

1. Install openjdk8 via:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless 
   sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-$(dpkg --print-architecture)
   ```
2. Enter this command via terminal to open SciLab-GUI:

   ```
   scilab
   ```
3. Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (after `jlatexmath` warning)

it's (the GUI and all of it's features) running without any problems including XCos (very good Simulink alternative).

By pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> I just skipped the warning

```
Could not find Java package '/usr/share/java/jlatexmath-fop-1.0.6.jar
```

If you don't need it, just don't install it.

Comment: You may want to write a comment below my answer about skipping jlatexmath part. Otherwise your answer do not contain new information and you should delete it. ATOMS in such case remain broken, to there are no tradeoffs. Scilab will continue to crash when started from Applcations menu/dash.

Comment: jlatexmath problem is now fixed. Consider to remove your answer as outdated.

Comment: This just worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer to a question raised in https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15390, I am able to run SCILAB 6.0.2 (debian package) without the error (*"libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"*).

It seems SCILAB 6.0.2 requires OpenJDK 11. I just added the path of the installed java to the `.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

The `scilab` GUI works fine for now, however, there are few minor errors.