# How to get Scilab 6.0.1 working on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: java, openjdk, scilab, 18.10

I have installed clean Ubuntu MATE 18.10 and installed Scilab from repository here with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

After installation I tried to launch it from GUI (*Applications → Other → Scilab*) - it does not start.
Then I tried to launch it from terminal with `scilab` command. Terminal output is as follows:

> $ scilab
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.class.path=/usr/share/java/flexdock.jar:/usr/share/java/skinlf.jar:/usr/share/java/looks.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/java/jhall.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queryparser-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-util/debian/freehep-util-debian.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-io/debian/freehep-io-debian.jar:/usr/share/maven-repo/org/freehep/freehep-graphicsio/debian/freehep-graphicsio-debian.jar:/usr/share/java/freehep-graphicsio-emf-2.1.jar:/usr/share/java/freehep-graphics2d-2.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/jrosetta-API.jar:/usr/share/java/jrosetta-engine-1.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/jgraphx.jar:/usr/share/java/jogl2.jar:/usr/share/java/gluegen2-rt.jar:/usr/share/java/jeuclid-core.jar:/usr/share/java/jlatexmath-fop-1.0.7.jar:/usr/share/java/fop.jar:/usr/share/java/saxon.jar:/usr/share/java/batik.jar:/usr/share/java/xml-apis-ext.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-io.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlgraphics-commons.jar:/usr/share/java/avalon-framework.jar:/usr/share/java/jlatexmath-1.0.7.jar:/usr/share/java/ecj.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/org.scilab.modules.helptools.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_ru_RU_help.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_images.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/helptools/jar/scilab_en_US_help.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graphic_objects/jar/org.scilab.modules.graphic_objects.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/renderer/jar/org.scilab.modules.renderer.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/scinotes/jar/org.scilab.modules.scinotes.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/localization/jar/org.scilab.modules.localization.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graph/jar/org.scilab.modules.graph.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/jvm/jar/org.scilab.modules.jvm.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/preferences/jar/org.scilab.modules.preferences.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/scirenderer/jar/scirenderer.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/gui/jar/org.scilab.modules.gui.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/graphic_export/jar/org.scilab.modules.graphic_export.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/action_binding/jar/org.scilab.modules.action_binding.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/xcos/jar/org.scilab.modules.xcos.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/ui_data/jar/org.scilab.modules.ui_data.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/types/jar/org.scilab.modules.types.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/history_manager/jar/org.scilab.modules.history_manager.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/external_objects_java/jar/org.scilab.modules.external_objects_java.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/console/jar/org.scilab.modules.console.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/history_browser/jar/org.scilab.modules.history_browser.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/javasci/jar/org.scilab.modules.javasci.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/completion/jar/org.scilab.modules.completion.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/commons/jar/org.scilab.modules.commons.jar:/usr/share/scilab/modules/core/jar/org.scilab.modules.core.jar:
>   --add-modules=java.activation,java.xml.bind
>          Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>          java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

So I reported [bug 1798661](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1798661) to the LaunchPad.

It seems that I need to get `java.xml.bind` from some package.
According to [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=java.xml.bind) I need to install `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` package, but it does not have needed file in Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic.

Note: I do not want to download and extract binary archive from Scilab web-site (but this [is a workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029164/66509)). I need the solution with deb-packages using APT.

What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays Scilab is ported to OpenJDK 11. So we have to install it with (if not installed before):

```
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

So we can use latest scilab package 6.0.1-7ubuntu1~18.10 as usual from GUI, but `scilab-cli` and `scilab-adv-cli` are now broken (it is new [bug 1825037](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scilab/+bug/1825037)).

Note 1: Scilab color theme is incompatible with dark Gtk themes, so user should set light one (this is [bug 1547561](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1547561)) such as *Radiance* or *Radiant-MATE*.

Note 2: Scilab ATOMS system is broken too (see [bug 1765503](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1765503)) because of problems with HDF5.

---

To prevent this bugs we need to install binary version as written in [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029164/66509) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS .